# How to sign a transaction automatically?

Tags: web3js, transactions, dapps, raw-transaction

An api will call the smart contract function. It should sign the transaction on its own instead of human intervention.

I think raw transaction can work here. Are there any other options?

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

--Edit--
The question is updated!

Comment: Do you mean contract should sign its own transaction?

Comment: Yes! it should complete the transaction on its own.

Comment: So why did you tag the question under `web3.js`?

Comment: `It should sign the transaction on its own` - the API or the contract? (I don't see how the contract could possibly do that, but you just wrote it in a comment above).

Comment: I know contract can't sign the transaction on its own. I found my answer it should be done by raw transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (using web3.js v1):

```
let Web3 = require("web3");
let web3 = new Web3(NODE_ADDRESS);

async function send(transaction, reestimate = function(gas) {return gas;}) {
    let gas = await transaction.estimateGas({from: PUBLIC_KEY});
    let options = {
        to  : transaction._parent._address,
        data: transaction.encodeABI(),
        gas : reestimate(gas)
    };
    let signedTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, PRIVATE_KEY);
    return await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction);
}
```

Usage example #1:

```
let receipt = await send(myContract.methods.myFunc(arg1, arg2, arg3));
...
```

Usage example #2:

```
let reestimate = function(gas) {return gas * 2;};
let receipt = await send(myContract.methods.myFunc(arg1, arg2, arg3), reestimate);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

A contract can not sign transaction by its own. The transaction must be signed by externally owned accounts. If a transaction is not signed by an externally owned account then it won't be included in the blockchain.

Comment: This is why I'm pretty sure that this user doesn't really mean to ask how the contract can sign its own transaction, but how the (external) API should sign the transaction (even though he/she stated the opposite in response to your comment). An evidence to that is the fact that the question is tagged under `web3.js`. In addition, there's no sense in asking how to sign a transaction from the on-chain, because signing a transaction is performed from the off-chain **by definition**.

Comment: @goodvibration I agree with you. Even I was confused after reading the question and asked for more clarification.